what is reason behind my existence?
ok before starting I am good at science. so, I believe in existence Allah The creator of us because science doesn't always ends with dot it will ended as comma. Few weeks ago I was on bus and saw a man who pulling cart of load. It was pity site that he was full of sweet the load might be above 50 or 70 kg which used to pull by cow but he is pulling it all by himself. then a question appeared on my head. I heard Allah was kind hearted person than anyone then why..? me who doesn't work that much and always want help someone but i can't living a good life but why he doesn't deserve it. I started to doubt my own existence and it's aching my head till now. can someone tell me why this all

From your question I guess you are talking about difficulties in Dunya. The answer is that Dunya is something like a bonus level in the whole life of a human. It is so short compared to the whole life, but people can grow/fail to a great extent, not easily achievable/compensated in the hereafter. Dunya life is such short in the whole time-line that in Qiyamah people argue how much time did they spent in Dunya, and they consider the time as long as a few hours perhaps.

قَالَ كَمْ لَبِثْتُمْ فِي الْأَرْضِ عَدَدَ سِنِينَ؟ قَالُوا لَبِثْنَا
يَوْمًا أَوْ بَعْضَ يَوْمٍ فَاسْأَلِ الْعَادِّينَ . قَالَ إِنْ
لَبِثْتُمْ إِلَّا قَلِيلًا لَوْ أَنَّكُمْ كُنْتُمْ تَعْلَمُونَ
[Allah] will say, 'How long did you remain on earth in number of
years?' They will say, 'We remained a day or part of a day; ask those
who enumerate.' He will say, 'You stayed not but a little - if only
you had known.'

Also think about what is Dunya? Dunya is a place for people to bear the difficulties and grow:

لَقَدْ خَلَقْنَا الْإِنْسَانَ فِي كَبَدٍ
We have certainly created man into hardship.

and will rewarded in Qiyamah accordingly, if they bear the difficulties in good faith, and grow.
